# jquery slide adding content with image slide container

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

First to explain current functionality:
On my webpage I’m using [jquery cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) to slide images. This works perfectly, but now I want to extend this functionality in order to add and text for each image inside slide.
Inside view I have

```
<div id="background-slides">
      <div class="slide">
            <img src="/Images/slider/0.jpg" alt="initial image" />
       </div>
 </div>
```

On the same page inside view I’m adding slide images

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        var backgroundSlides = new Array();
        backgroundSlides.push('/Images/slider/1.jpg');
        backgroundSlides.push('/Images/slider/2.jpg');
        backgroundSlides.push('/Images/slider/3.jpg');
</script>
if ($('#background-slides .slide').length) {
      $('#background-slides').cycle({
            speed: 1000,
            swipe: true,
            delay: 2000,
            timeout: 6000,
            fx: 'zoom',
            slides: '.slide',
            next: '.right',
            prev: '.left'
        });
       $.each(backgroundSlides,
                function (intIndex, objValue) {
                    var newSlide = '<div class="slide"><img src="' + objValue + '" /></div>';
                    $('#background-slides').cycle('add', newSlide);
                }
       );
     }
});
```

My question is:
How can on each slide change add div with some content related to that slide, for example MSG 1 on Slide 1, MSG 2 on Slide 2, etc.

Comment: From what I see `cycle` only works with images. That means you cannot add any content to them. You could use the `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements of each image, but there are so many limitations, downsides and potential browser incompatibilities that it's not a good idea. You need to look for a plugin that animates divs, not images if that's what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an extra div to your images style it with CSS and animated with js, the code is too long to place it here but just to help you going I have made a fiddle for you. Just see the fiddle example here below in the comment.

Comment: Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6t0ce4Lb/. Please note that in the fiddle the plugin code is in the 'javascript' part just to make this working but you don't need there because you already have it.